# Reset Password working in local but in live not working - using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, passwords

i am unable to reset the password twice for the same email address, the first time i can reset and second time i click on password reset link it show me empty page and redirect me to the home url i dont know whats happening but its working fine in local no issue if i make request on same email address multiple times i can reset password on local successfully but i cannot reset password on live if i already reset it.

I have also attached the screen shot of my view:

My Controller:

```
public function forgot(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => "Your email address was not found.",
        ], 401);
    }

    try {
        $token = str_random(64);

        DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'token' => bcrypt($token),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);

        $user->reset_token = $token;

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new ForgotPassword($user));

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //Return with error
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false, 'errors' => $error_message], 401);
    }


    return response()->json([
        'success' => true, 'message' => 'A reset email has been sent! Please check your email.'
    ]);
}
```

And my Reset password controller:

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{ 
    use ResetsPasswords;
}
```

My Routes:

```
<?php

Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.request');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Home Controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

My forgot.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome Email</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Hello {{$user['first_name']}}</h2>
<br/>
You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.
<br/>
<a href="{{url('password/reset', $user->reset_token)}}">Reset Password</a>
<br/>
<p>
    If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.<br/>
    Regards,<br/>
    <strong>Triple R Lense</strong>
</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

What I see:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can check the response code the server returns when you see this blank page? Also if you navigate directly to `/ovada_cm_fd_backend/home` is it normally a blank page, or only after the redirect?

Comment: its after a redirect